# Not a valid Windows application error in PHPStorm file watcher

Tags: path, phpstorm

Here's what I get in my CMD:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>lessc

lessc: no input files

... (long program output)

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator
\Dane aplikacji\npm\lessc"
lessc: no input files

usage: lessc [option option=parameter ...] <source> [destination]

... (long program output)

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

But when I add a file watcher in my PHPStorm for LESS and specify the program to:
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Dane aplikacji\npm\lessc, I get the following error:

```
16:52:38 An exception occurred while executing watcher 'LESS'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Dane aplikacji\npm\lessc" (in directory "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Pulpit\bootstrap\css"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 nie jest prawid³ow¹ aplikacj¹ systemu Wi
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to forgot how Windows/DOS works ;)

When you trying to execute `lessc` **in Command Shell**, Windows will search for such file. If nothing found -- it will search for `lessc.exe`, `lessc.com`, `lessc.bat`, `lessc.cmd` and so on -- depends on value of `PATHEXT` environment variable. Just type `SET` in command prompt and see for yourself.

In PhpStorm (or any other software) where NO command shell is used but command executed DIRECTLY, **you have to specify FULL program name, which is `lessc.cmd`**

Comment: Oops sorry, earlier I used .bat instead of .cmd but now I checked and it was .cmd, that's why it didn't work even with full path. Thanks!